# How to manage Presence Subscription requests with smack on Android

Tags: android, xmpp

I want to know the best practice to send presence requests during registration.

I am developing a chat app on android. The user account id is based on phone numbers.

The approach is like this.

1. Read all contacts from Phone.
2. Create a list of all phone numbers you need to send presence requests to.
3. When the list reaches 50 numbers. Send a Multicast message using
   XEP-0033. This is to reduce network
       calls.

The issue with this approach is that a user normally has 500-600 contacts on his phone or maybe more. On an average the registration process might take 10-12 http calls for presence subscriptions.

Can somebody suggest a better approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your framework is something like that of *Whatsapp*.

Now, for that I can refer you to opensource alternative of *Whatsapp* that is ***Kontalk***.

You can find the Github code [here](https://github.com/kontalk/androidclient).

You can go through the code, hope it helps.